# Where did Jiraiya obtain important information?

Tags: naruto

Jiraiya knows some information that is not easily obtained, such as the fact that the Akatsuki clan were hunting Naruto, or that Orochimaru will be using Sasuke for three more years. How Jiraiya get that important information?

Comment: Just a speculation but I do remember Sasori being involved in leaking inside info to Kabuto or something like that. I think something similar might have been possible in this case. Maybe Sasori or someone else leaked the info to Jiraiya. Don't as me why they would do that.

Answer (score 2):

Jiraiya has a spy network. His spy network is one of the best in the ninja world second to only Akatsuki.

1. Sasuke couldn't be used as Orochimaru's new body because Orochimaru already had switched bodies. Why? Sasuke couldn't be delivered to Orochimaru in time. Sasuke and the Sound 4 were delayed by the Konoha Genin.
2. It is said that Itachi Uchiha had revealed some info on Akatsuki to the third Hokage,

Comment: This doesn't really explain how he got the info on Akatsuki.

Comment: Kisame and Itachi came to kidnap Naruto, Jiraiya made them retreat.
Many jinchurikis were being kidnapped.

Jiraiya connected that.

Comment: That's possible. Jiraiya could have figured that.